# For caches, how do you determine which block do write to for a highly associative set?

Tags: caching

Let's say that there is a set with capacity 1024, block size 32, set associativity 4, and 8 sets. Based on this, there are 24 tag bits, 3 set index bits, and 5 block offset bits. I want to write something from a values array into the cache (let's say, values[1][0], which is at address 0x256, or 0b1001010110. This means that I am writing to set 2 (the set index bits, which are 010, tell me this). However, I don't know how to determine which of the four blocks in set 2 to write to.

Comment: Isn't the point of a set that you can write the line into any of the blocks?

Comment: If that's the case, then I misunderstood how caches work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite how set associativity works. Once we locate a set for a given address, we can put the data into any of the cache lines in the set. If the block only mapped to a specific line, it'd be tantamount to a direct mapped cache.

For perspective, a fully associative cache is on the other extreme: any block can map to any line in the cache. This is useful for small and fast caches such as TLBs. The rationale is that direct mapping offers quick lookup speeds (there's only one line to check for a given block), but suffers from high rates of conflict misses where blocks that map to the same line cause frequent evictions. Since TLBs are typically small, the lookup time isn't much of a problem and increasing the hit rate will have a more significant impact on the average memory access time.

Set associativity is a balance knob between direct mapped and fully associative caches with the aim of maximizing miss penalty versus lookup speed.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_placement_policies#Set_Associative_Cache) says about set associative caches:

> The Set associative cache can be imagined as a (n*m) matrix. The cache is divided into ‘n’ sets and each set contains ‘m’ cache lines. A memory block is first mapped onto a set and then placed into any cache line of the set.